# java.net.SocketException:socketfailed:EACCES(permission denied) for OTP application in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-permissions, permission-denied, one-time-password, android-internet

I am trying to create an One time password access android application. I have created a local host server using wamp and I am trying to access that thing with the mobile application I have designed. Unfortunately, I am getting the error as following in my log cat:

```
03-07 10:42:35.097 31217-31217/com.example.user.myapplication V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{1ecab2fb token=android.os.BinderProxy@23c38b5b {com.example.user.myapplication/com.example.user.myapplication.activity.SmsActivity}} show : true
03-07 10:42:36.607 31217-31217/com.example.user.myapplication I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@23c38b5b time:52633449
03-07 10:42:37.397 31217-31217/com.example.user.myapplication D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
03-07 10:42:37.537 31217-32544/com.example.user.myapplication E/SmsActivity: Posting params: {email=thomasbi@gmail.com, name=Thomas, mobile=9002378900}
03-07 10:42:37.537 31217-32544/com.example.user.myapplication I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
03-07 10:42:37.537 31217-32544/com.example.user.myapplication I/System.out: KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
03-07 10:42:37.547 31217-31217/com.example.user.myapplication E/SmsActivity: Error: java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
03-07 10:42:37.617 31217-31217/com.example.user.myapplication D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered!
```

I have included all of the permissions, here's my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:name=".app.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SmsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sms">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

    </activity>

    <!-- SMS Receiver -->
    <receiver android:name=".receiver.SmsReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="99999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <!-- Intent service -->
    <service
        android:name=".service.HttpService"
        android:exported="false" />

</application>
```

I am bit confused at the moment and I understand I am stuck with something silly. I would be deeply obliged if anyone could help me with the issue.

Comment: are you try to run application on marshmallow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting API 23+ (Marshmallow), permission requests are made when a permission is required, not doing so can result in an unwanted user experience.

This site has a good explanation and examples:
http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal

Comment: So i need to raise a request for every permission i use?

Comment: How about if i change by compile sdk version to API 21, will that thing work?